# Как обратится к элементу у которого нет класса и id?

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="modals-container">...</div>
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: 777; width: 1900px; height: 870px">
```

Как можно обратится к элементу без id и класса? Можно ли к нему обратится зная id предыдущего элемента? Можно ли обратится к такому элементу через свойство стиля?
Спасибо за любую помощь заранне!

Comment: да. через родительский блок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можно ли к нему обратится зная id предыдущего элемента

Да, можно, для этого обращаемся к `#modals-container` и получаем следующий от него элемент через метод [`.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling):

```
document.querySelector('#modals-container').nextElementSibling
```

---

> Можно ли обратится к такому элементу через свойство стиля?

Тоже можно.
Используйте `document.querySelector()`, таким образом у вас есть возможность достучаться до элемента через селекторы..
В селекторах есть возможность обращаться к атрибутам по содержимому, тут нам пригодится оператор [`*=`](https://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/attr5), а далее делаем вот такой запрос и получаем данный элемент:

```
document.querySelector('div[style*="z-index: 777;"]')
```

---

Оба эти варианта будут куда быстрее, чем в ещё одном ответе, где мы собираем все `div` элементы со страницы и проходим по ним в поисках того самого.

Лично я бы выбрал именно второй вариант, т.к. если вдруг после элемента `#modals-container` появится какой-то другой, то скрипт получит уже другой элемент.. В прочем такое может случиться и со вторым вариантом, но мне кажется крайне мала вероятность встретить на странице ещё один `div` элемент с `z-index: 777`.

---

> Ещё вопросик. А как скрыть этот элемент через JS

Скорее всего этот элемент появляется в вёрстке не сразу при инициализации скрипта, а когда-то после, по этому советую отложить до `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var el = document.querySelector('div[style*="z-index: 777;"]')
  if(el) el.style.display = "none";
}
```

Данный код выполнится когда полностью загрузится страница и если в этот момент данный элемент будет существовать, в противном случае предлагаю использовать вариант с [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: De.Minov спасибо за ответ. Ещё вопросик. А как скрыть этот элемент через JS
`document.querySelector('div[style*="z-index: 777;"]').style.display = "none";` что-то не работает у меня.

Comment: @User, дополнил ответ

Answer (score -1):

можно для поиска необходимого блока использовать заранее известные параметры стилей

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(x=>{
  if(x.style.zIndex == '777')
      x.innerHTML += ' [current]'
})
```